# How to increment alpha value on scroll from 0.2 to 1 when user scrolls down?

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to show an image above a `ScrollView` and the more the user scrolls down, the more it gets visible. Ideally I want it to have an initial alpha of 0.2, and increasing to 1 when the scroll view has completely scrolled to the bottom.

I know that I can use a listener:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.my_scroll_view).setOnScrollChangeListener(new android.view.View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(android.view.View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                myImageButton.setAlpha(/* how to get this value? */);
            }
});
```

But I don't know how to fetch accurately the `ScrollView`'s height and compare it with the `scrollX` value I'm getting in the listener. Even more, when I try to scroll at the bottom of the `ScrollView`, here are the params that I'm fetching:

[image]

Now retrieving the view (`v`) height:

[image]

I don't understand how these results are related...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the correct value for the alpha, we'll need to divide the current scroll value by the maximum scroll value.

One would think that `ScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount()` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to output the value we need. What we really need is the view height of the ScrollView's child, minus its top and bottom padding.

So the current scroll value divided by that is our calulcated alpha. Then we just set the calculated alpha to `0.2f` if it's less than that!

The following code works for me:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.my_scroll_view).setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        View child = scrollView.getChildAt(0);
        int maxScroll = Math.max(0, child.getHeight() - (scrollView.getHeight() - scrollView.getPaddingBottom() - scrollView.getPaddingTop()));

        float calculatedAlpha = (float)scrollY / (float)maxScroll;
        if (calculatedAlpha < 0.2f) {
            calculatedAlpha = 0.2f;
        }

        myImageButton.setAlpha(calculatedAlpha);
    }
});
```